# Calling a Method at NSDate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, methods, nsdate

I'm trying to call a method at a certain time and date (using an `NSDate`) but I can't work out how to do it.

I don't want to use `NSTimer` because that becomes paused when the app goes into the background or is closed. I don't want to run one in the background either because this only solves half of the problem and is a wasteful way of doing it in my opinion. I thought that if I could fire a method at an `NSDate` in the future, when the app is opened again I can see if the current date has passed the fire date and so whether to call it instantly or carry on waiting.

I suppose I'm looking for something like `UILocalNotification`, without the notification.

I am hoping that there is a simple way of doing this that I just can't seem to find, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it sounded to me like you want the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method. So you have an `NSDate *date` when you want to call the selector.

```
NSTimeInterval delay = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
[self performSelector:@selector(methodToFire) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

Of course, this won't live past your runtime, so you've pretty much outlined what you need to do already. You just save your date somewhere (there are MANY ways to do that), and then check against it in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. You can use the same `timeIntervalSinceNow` method I used above. (If the date has past, the the interval would be negative.)

```
if ( [date timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0 ) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I'm going to use. Was kinda hoping there was going to be a `performSelector:withObject:atDate:` but I think I was hoping for something that isn't there. :-) Any reason to use `[self performSelector:@selector(methodToFire) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];` over `NSTimer`?

Comment: Not that I can think of, the timer is more code, I think, but offers more flexibility (which you probably don't need).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the NSTimer, and in the...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

callback, check the time and date, and update the timer, or call the function if the date has passed.

Comment: I want to try an stay away form timers as much as possible to keep performance to the max. Any reason to use `NSTimer` over `[self performSelector:@selector(methodToFire) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];`?

Comment: @Baza207 So that you can keep on updating your UI, without having to deal with threads. (Also a NSTimer with a slow fire rate is very performant, Id make sure that you profile before prematurely optimizing.)

Comment: Ah Oki. That helps my decision. Thanks a lot for your help. :-D